# message `sh "-c" "node server.js"` failed with 1 openshift error

Tags: node.js, sockets, openshift

Hello i recently use redhat openshift and i got error when i run "rhc tail -a {application}".

i got error code :

  -

---

---

npm ERR! message `sh "-c" "node server.js"` failed with 1

and my code:

```
var fs = require('fs');
var db_helper = require("./db_helper.js");
var ipaddr = process.env.OPENSHIFT_INTERNAL_IP;
var port = process.env.OPENSHIFT_INTERNAL_PORT || 8080;
var http = require('http');
http.createServer().listen(port, ipaddr, function(){
console.log('Server started on %s...', Date(Date.now()));
});
var io = require('socket.io').listen(http);



io.sockets.on('connection',  function(client) {
  console.log('Client connected'); 



  client.on('status', function(data) {
    console.log(data);
      db_helper.get_status(data,function(data) {
        io.sockets.emit('populate', data);

      });

  });
  db_helper.get_statusadmin(function(data) {
        io.sockets.emit('adminpopulate', data);

      });
  client.on('statusadmin', function (data) {
    db_helper.get_statusadmin(function(data) {
        io.sockets.emit('adminpopulate', data);

      });
  });

});
```

How to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

OpenShift uses `npm start` to initialize node.js applications.  This takes advantage of your app's `package.json` file, allowing you to define your initialization code by updating the "main" attribute.

`sh "-c" "node server.js"` is what `npm start` is calling for you.  It sounds like your code contains an error.

I'd try running and debugging your app locally before you deploy.

Comment: It would be nice if it would output the actual error instead of requiring me to shell in and run it.